# Check what is the first letter of a string

Tags: python

I am writing a function to explain the first charachter of a string. If it is a capital it should return 'upper', if  a lower then 'lower', if a digit then 'digit' else 'other'

```
def solution(s):
    c = s[0]
    if c.isupper() == True:    
        return "upper"
```

The above is not returning true for "Hello".
How to go ahead?

Comment: Your code is working and is returning 'upper' (why do you expect *True*?) for `solution('Hello')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `isdigit` and `islower` methods

```
def solution(s):
    c = s[0]
    
    if c.isupper():    
        return "upper"
    elif c.islower():
        return "lower"
    elif c.isdigit():
        return "digit"
    else:
        return "other"
```

You can also test this function:

```
print(solution("hello world!"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I agree with your advice and I have updated my code to reflect it. I am also new to python so this is a learning experience for me as well :)